# SharePoint 2010 list logic calculated column

Tags: list

I need to record number of points for each seminar attended **[points received]** and the points remaining **[points remaining]**.

For example, for attending each seminar I get 2 points and the total number of points to receive is 15. So after I attend one seminar, I have 13 points remaining, after I attend the 2nd seminar, I have 11 points remaining, etc.

Is it possible to have a calculated column in SharePoint list to display this information?
I tried the following formula for the points `remaining = 15 - [points received]`, but it always gives me 13 points in the **[points remaining]** column.

I also tried `= [points remaining] - [points received]`, this gives me an error:

`"The formula contains a circular reference (the calculated column refers to itself)."`

Could you please provide any suggestions? If a calculated column is not an option here, what else I could use to achieve the task of recording this information in a list?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you familiar with programming you can have a look on Event Receivers.
Here you have instructions how to implement such [receiver](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough4/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem you will have are the states you described with the increment of a course. The column calculation doesn't work with different states as far as I know.

You could either use a [workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx) that starts on the modification of the **points received** column and manipulates the required value of **[points remaining]**.

The other option would be a [JavaScript file added to the EditForm via the Content-Editor](http://sharepointadam.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp/) Webpart of the List that would take care of the logic while editing the list values.